# What is the best way to protect my DB class from being hacked

Tags: php, oop

I Have a class called 'DBinterface' and a class called 'user'.

1. is it perfectly fine for the connect function to be public?

   ```
   class dbinterface {

       private $_dbLink;
   private $dbHost = 'host';
       private $dbUser = 'user';
       private $dbName = 'name';
       private $dbPass = 'pass';
       private $dbUserTable = 'table';

    public function connect ()
   {
       $this->_dbLink = mysql_connect($this->_dbHost, $this->_dbUser, $this->_dbPass);
       if(!$this->_dbLink) 
           throw new Exception ("Could not connect to database. " . mysql_error());
   }
   ```
2. I have a sql table that stores all my users information like userID and password. can i put the name of that table into a function like this without the risk of someone somwhat easily hacking it, or should i put it with my db class?

   ```
   function registerUser($userName, $userPassword) {

       $db = new db();
       $db->connect();

       // Select database
       mysql_select_db($this->dbName);

       $query = "insert into usersExample values (NULL, \"$userName\", \"$userPassword\")";
       $result = mysql_query($query);

       // Test to make sure query worked
       if(!$result) die("Query didn't work. " . mysql_error());

       // Get the user ID
       $this->userID = mysql_insert_id();

       // Close database connection
       mysql_close($dbLink);

   } // End registerUser()
   ```

PS: i have removed password encryption and escape string for legibility.

Comment: Users cannot arbitrarily call functions that are marked public, and unless you're allowing the end user to call `registerUser` themself, no, it's fine, just sanitize your input...

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're asking what the best way to escape data before insert is?

Did you look into [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)?

Or are you asking about web security in general? Like making sure nobody can somehow reveal your database info or call the script directly?

You can nest your DB credentials beneath root and include them in this class. You can also prevent directly calling any file by defining a constant elsewhere in a common file and including something like this in the header of every class file:

```
<?php defined('IN_APP') or die('No access allowed.');
```

where obviously you would define IN_APP somewhere else:

```
define('IN_APP', true);
```

If I missed the point feel free to comment and I will adjust as best I can.

Comment: I am asking about web security in general. I looked but i cant find mucn information on "IN_APP" other than how to use it. What is it or do you know a link that will explain it?

Comment: IN_APP is just a string. You can call it whatever you want. define('LOL'); so elsewhere in your oop code - a constructor or something - you include your db config that has this definition. That way defined('LOL') or die('no access') will be granted if your constructor is called first and die if you try to call the script directly. Course, htaccess could also do this in one line. we use both just cause most frameworks default to this redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure there's no way to retrieve php files from your web server -- that is, they will execute, but will not be returned. Even with that assurance though, I would not place your database password within the php file for several reasons, one of which is security. Instead, I would place the connection details (all, not just password) in a text file which your php script knows how to find (and read), however the text file is not in the same directory as the php and, if you can control this, not even in a directory your web server can provide GET/PORT access to. If that control isn't available, at a minimum, have an .htaccess that assures your text file is not to be accessed through any direct URL.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be too worried about it. If a hacker was to execute code on your machine anyways they would try to use an open sql handler, not your class.